# No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public". function transfer(address receiver, uint amount);

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I am doing a criptoCoin and I am using Solidity. I have an issue when create a crowdsale on `function transfer(address receiver, uint amount);
} the compile said No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
function transfer(address receiver, uint amount);
^-----------------------------------------------^\`

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking us what public means?

Comment: @elsyr yes can't able to write contract of crowdsale I don't know wrong with Ethereum code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing necessarily wrong with your code - the compiler is just warning you that you didn't specify a visibility scope, and that it'll be defaulting it to `public`.

Something like this is probably what you want:

```
function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) external {}
```

The `external` keyword just means that the function can only be called from outside the contract - i.e. by other contracts/addresses on the Ethereum network. Other options include `public`, `private`, and `internal`. You can read more about these visibility keywords [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters).

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.4.16;
interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount);
}contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public deadline;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;
    event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

Comment: Again, not sure what your question is - all you've done is paste code (unformatted!) into the comments section.

Comment: And? What is your question?

Comment: I m using this codeine ether wallet but can't able to compile.and received this errir
No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount);
    ^-----------------------------------------------^
,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161896/discussion-between-hassan-abbas-and-elsyr).